# Alternative to Xor

Tags: vb.net

I've been given the following method:

```
Private Sub boldButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles boldButton.Click
    Dim curFont As Font
    Dim newFont As Font
    curFont = rtb.SelectionFont
    If curFont IsNot Nothing Then
        'create the new font
        newFont = New Font(curFont.FontFamily, curFont.Size, curFont.Style Xor FontStyle.Bold)
        'set it
        rtb.SelectionFont = newFont
    End If
End Sub
```

Currently having problems understanding what is happening with this part of the code `curFont.Style Xor FontStyle.Bold`. What is a valid way to achieve the same result without using the `operator` `Xor` ?

**EDIT** (As commented by us2012) Do I need an alternative?

I've looked up [**Xor on MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csw1x2a6.aspx) but still having trouble understanding the implementation of it in `boldButton_Click` procedure.

Comment: Why do you need a different way if this one works?

Comment: @us2012 - because I don't understand it! ... an alternative will hopefully help me understand

Comment: @us2012 - think I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitwise XOR toggles a flag. Let's assume that the Style bitfield looks like this

```
00000000
     ^^^
     BIU (Bold, Italic, Underline)
```

So the value of `FontStyle.Bold` would be:

```
00000100
```

Now `something Xor FontStyle.Bold` will just flip this bit in `something`. Example:

```
00000111 Xor 00000100 = 00000011    (Boldness removed)
00000001 Xor 00000100 = 00000101    (Boldness added)
```

Note that the other bits are unaffected.

---

Since you explicitly asked for alternatives: You could check whether the bit is set `style And Bold <> 0`, and then either set it `style = style Or Bold` or remove it `style = style And (Not Bold)`.

Comment: +1 thanks for alternative - although as @us2012 guessed I need to read up a little bit(excuse pun) on bitwise operations first

Answer (score 4):

Judging from your comment that you don't understand what `Xor` does here, I think an explanation will help you more than an artificial alternative construction. If you want to understand how this works, you first need to know about [bitwise operations.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) Once you know that, imagine that for a font, the font styles are saved as 0s and 1s. For simplicity's sake, let's say there are 3 bits, the first one for bold, the second for italic, the third one for underlined. (So 101 is bold underlined, 011 is italic underlined, etc. Furthermore, `FontStyle.Bold` is 100 etc.).

Then, in analogy with the bitwise operations:

`oldstyle Or FontStyle.Bold` creates a new style that is bold, no matter whether the old style was. (If `oldstyle` was `FontStyle.Italic` = `010`, then `010 Or 100` = `110`, so the new style is bold italic.)

`oldstyle Xor FontStyle.Bold` creates a new style which is bold if the old style wasn't, and not bold if the old style was bold. (Let's say `oldstyle` was both bold and italic, so `110`, then `110 Xor 100` is `010`, so italic only. If however the old style was normal `000`, then `000 Xor 100` is `100`, so just bold.)

Comment: ok +1 - I'll read the bitwise reference before doing anything else!